# The Odatav4 Expand query not working properly in Blazor server project

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, blazor-server-side, odata-v4

When I try to expand the **OrdDetails** using the expand property in OData, it works properly. However, when I try to access **OrdDetailsData**, I encounter an error.

1.**https://localhost:44324/odata/Orders?$expand=OrdDetails  --this one working**
"
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44324/odata/$metadata#Orders(OrdDetails())","value":[{"Id":1,"ParentId":1,"HasChild":true,"Summary":"somevalue","Created":"2023-01-23T10:00:08+05:30","OrdDetailsData":{"SecondId":1110},"OrdDetails":{"Id":111}},{"Id":2,"ParentId":2,"HasChild":true,"Summary":"somevalue1","Created":"2023-01-24T10:00:08+05:30","OrdDetailsData":{"SecondId":2220},"OrdDetails":{"Id":222}}]}

2.https://localhost:44324/odata/Orders?$expand=OrdDetailsData
"

Same scenario, I am expanding the **OrdDetailsData,** but I have faced the below error. How to solve this problem?

"
{"error":{"code":"","message":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'OrdDetailsData' on type 'Sirrusss.Client.Order' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.","details":[],"innererror":{"message":"Property 'OrdDetailsData' on type 'Sirrusss.Client.Order' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.","type":"Microsoft.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.ParseComplexTypesBeforeNavigation(IEdmStructuralProperty edmProperty, PathSegmentToken& currentToken, List`1 pathSoFar)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.GenerateExpandItem(ExpandTermToken tokenIn)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Bind(ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo, ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpand()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.get_SelectExpandClause()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Validator.SelectExpandQueryValidator.Validate(SelectExpandQueryOption selectExpandQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Validator.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)"}}}
"

**
This is my model class
**

```
 public class Order
 {

     public Order() { }

     public int? Id { get; set; }

     public int? ParentId { get; set; }

     public bool? HasChild { get; set; }

     public string? Summary { get; set; }

     public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
     
     public virtual Details OrdDetails { get; set; }

     public virtual DetailsData OrdDetailsData { get; set; }

 }

public class Details
 {
     public Details() { }

     public int Id { get; set; }
 }

 public class DetailsData
 {

     public DetailsData() { }

     public int SecondId { get; set; }
 }
```

**In Program.cs file**

```
using BlazorDataGridODatav4;
using BlazorDataGridODatav4.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;
using Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder;


static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.Namespace = "Sirrusss.Client";
      var orgUnits = builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddOData(opt => { opt.Select().Filter().Count().OrderBy().Expand().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel()); });
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(x => x
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                    .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

When I try to expand the **OrdDetails** using the expand property in OData, it works properly. However, when I try to access **OrdDetailsData**, I encounter an error. Anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `DetailsData` treated not as **Entity**, but as **ComplexType**. And that's why no navigation property added. And only navigation properties can be expanded.

`DetailsData` was not made **Entity**, because by Convention it not contains any Keys.
You can fix that by renaming `SecondId` -> `Id` or by adding `[Key]` as attribute:

```
    [Key]
    public int SecondId { get; set; }
```